# Search-Filter in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, batch-file, search, filter

I am trying to make a small Search engine for searching Id's in a HTML code. 
I have done sth. like that already in batch

```
dir * %typed% *
```

Then, all elements including the string "typed" came up. So, my question is: How can i do this in Javascript?

```
PS:
In Batch: * %var% *
In Javascript: ???
```

Thank you if you can help me!

Comment: Do you want to search for id _attributes_? I'd suggest not searching the raw html string but parsing it to DOM elements first. Then, you'll be able to use the `Document` utility functions such as `querySelectorAll` and `textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the `id`s of the page.

```
var ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
                     .map( el => el.getAttribute('id'))
                     .filter(Boolean)
```

Then you can check which one match to your pattern

```
var stringToSearch = 'typed';
ids.filter( id => id.includes( stringToSearch ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the string into a regex:

```
// Create the regex once
var searchString = 'something%typed%';
var rxString = searchString.replace(/%/g, '.*');
var regex = new RegExp(rxString, 'i');

// (...)
// Then, for each string you want to search:

var stringToCheck = 'something was typed somewhere';
var found = regex.test(stringToCheck);

alert(found);
```